# How to get physical memory addresses out of WSTP?

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

Appologies this is a very stupid question since I am learning c and wstp's input outputs.

Suppose I have a template file as follows:

```
:Begin:
:Function: test
:Pattern: test[]
:Arguments: { }
:ArgumentTypes: { }
:ReturnType: Manual
:End:
:Evaluate: test::usage = "test[] prints something"
```

For the following source:

```
#include "wstp.h"
#include "stdio.h"

void test() {
    //Manual
    char str[] = "hello";

    WSPutString(stdlink, printf("string str has starting address: %p",str));
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    return WSMain(argc, argv);
}
```

How to push out starting address of the string "hello" as a hex string value to mathematica?

If someone can fix this or just create another simple example of sending pointer value, i.e. address as hex to mathematica. I have successfully returned integer, double and string value to mathematica but don't know how to get pointer value out.

---

Also I can directly import all data types of c to mathematica except for pointer. Does mathematica have a high level representation of a memory address in some undocumented form?

Comment: Have you tried casting it to an integer, say with `(int) &str`?

Comment: That should be a cast to an unsigned integer of course.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau that cast should be to a [uintptr_t](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/stdint.h#Integers_wide_enough_to_hold_pointers) to be standards-conformant.

Comment: @Roman I was recommending a cast to an unsigned int specifically in case WSTP does not support pointer types (as claimed in the post; I have no experience with this myself).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau ok then a check (assertion) of `sizeof(unsigned int) == sizeof(&str)` or `sizeof(unsigned long int) == sizeof(&str)` might do.